# How to grant read-only (non-copy) access to an object in another process in Cython?

Tags: cython, cythonize

How to grant read-only (non-copy) access to an object in one process to another process?

For example, in the diagram below, how to grant `Process 2` and `Process 3` access to the class `Tasks` which is in `Process 1`?

`Process 1` is the only process which will write to the class `Tasks` and it is not important to maintain any state about which tasks have been processed etc.

```
Process 2                     Process 1                      Process 3
+-------------------+         +-------------------+          +-------------------+
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
| Perform job A for | <----------+ class Tasks +-----------> | Perform job B for |
| task in Tasks     |         |                   |          | task in Tasks     |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
|                   |         |                   |          |                   |
+-------------------+         +-------------------+          +-------------------+
```

I think this tasks may involve using pointers? [Cython's documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html) is brief on parallelism.

How to give `Process 2` and `Process 3` read-only, non-copy access to the class `Tasks` which is in `Process 1`?

Comment: There is no easy way to share memory between processes, besides a copy of the said memory, as far as I am aware. However because in Cython you have the possibility of releasing the GIL and thus using multi threading at its full potential, it might make more sense to have a multi threaded application, where each thread still share the same memory (being in the same process).

Comment: Guess the `many-PUB-s : many-SUB-s` may provide a tool for remotely-"injected" ( thus Read-Only ) copies, that can " *cross* " process-boundaries without any memory-violations. **`:o)`** obviously the lovely art of a Zen-of-Zero -- i.e. -- the **Zero-copy** would not work " *across* " process-private memory-boundaries.

Comment: Shared, no. Copied, yes. Processes do not share memory. In general you are better off using a producer/consumer model where data is put on a shared container, like a Queue, and data items are pulled from the queue by all processes. That way, each process/thread gets a distinct piece of work and does not need to share anything. The Queue itself is a container rather than shared memory , see `multiprocessing.Queue` and `Queue.Queue`. In the above example Process1 would add to queue, all other worker processes would pull from it.

Comment: @danny The [Queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) says that the `get` method will "remove and return an item from the queue." The reason for read-only is that for every item in `Tasks` there are multiple functions (e.g. `Process 1` and `Process 2`) which need the task as an input. The reason for non-copy is that each task object is large and there are many functions which need the input so creating a queue for each process and copying the task object each time is not ideal.

Comment: There are more suitable languages where multi threading is not constrained by the GIL (Java, C, C++ ...etc)  and might be suitable to your idea of sharing memory while using the available parallelism

Comment: @Greg That does not change the fact that processes do not share memory. How to approach the task needs to be re-considered. If you want to share memory, that means threads not processes.